# C# How to add Jarray to List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am new to C# .net .
I am trying to add my `Jarray` to a dictionary `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`  and then to a list `List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>`.

My string is something like :

```
Response = "[{\"name\":\"ABCD\",\"caption\":\"ABCDCaption\",\"description\":\"ABCDDesc\"},{\"name\":\"ABCD\",\"caption\":\"ABCDCaption\",\"description\":\"ABCDCaption\"},{\"name\":\"XYZ.exe\",\"caption\":\"XYZCaption\","description":\"XYZdesc\"}]"
```

The code is :

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(Response);

foreach (JObject o in bb.Children<JObject>())
{
foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
{
  string name = p.Name;
  var value = p.Value;
  DicSQLData.Add(key: name, value: value);                      

}
ListSQLData.Add(DicSQLData);

}
```

It works fine for first set of data

```
{\"name\":\"ABCD\",\"caption\":\"ABCDCaption\",\"description\":\"ABCDDesc\"}
```

For second set it gives error as dictionary does not add duplicate key.
How to fix this?
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> ListSQLData = new List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>();           
Dictionary<string, dynamic> DicSQLData = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

Comment: The keys in the dictionary must be unique, in your code you're trying to add a entry with name 'ABCD' more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we're missing some of the code, but you're seeing that error because you're not initializing a new dictionary on each loop iteration, you're inserting into the same dictionary causing the key errors.

Try doing this instead. Notice each iteration makes a new dictionary and then inserts it into the list

```
JArray a = JArray.Parse(Response);

foreach (JObject o in bb.Children<JObject>())
{
    //make new dictionary
    var DicSQLData = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

    foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
    {     
      string name = p.Name;
      var value = p.Value;
      DicSQLData.Add(key: name, value: value);                      
    }

    //add dictionary to list
    ListSQLData.Add(DicSQLData);
}
```

Comment: I initialised this: List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>> ListSQLData = new List<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(); Dictionary<string, dynamic> DicSQLData = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

Comment: You have to change your logic not the code: dictionaries can only have unique keys

Comment: @user13199266 Correct, but you only initialize the dictionary once in your code, which causes the key errors. In my answer it initializes a **new** dictionary on every iteration of the outer loop which prevents the errors.

Comment: @mituw16 O yes.. how did I miss this .. I declared disctionary just once. Thanks a lot . It worked . I will now never forget this logic. :)